# How to check accented characters by C#

Tags: c#

Example1: "Lina want to go to school. Mi rư xă". =>>>>result: true

Example2: "Lina want to go to school" =>>> result: false

I want to check if a string contains accented characters.

Comment: Define "*accented*". Do you count `ç` as an accented character, or `Ξ`, `©`, `±` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use the [`Normalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netcore-3.1) method with the appropriate [`NormalizationForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.normalizationform?view=netcore-3.1) then filtering by the *Unicode* category `NonSpacingMark`

**Update**

Do note though, accents are only a subset of `NonSpacingMark`. so this is not going to be reliable. I don't think there is a reliable way to do this without a list of accents.

```
public static bool HasDiacritics(string value)
{
   if (value == null) return false;

   var normalize = value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

   var sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (var t in normalize.Where(t => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(t) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark))
      sb.Append(t);

   return (sb.ToString() != value);
}
```

**Example**

```
var list = new List<string>(){
   "Lina want to go to school. Mi rư xă",
   "Lina want to go to school",
   "Lina want to go to sch`ool",
   "Lina want Ξ, ©, ±",
};
var results = list.Select(HasDiacritics);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
True
False
False
False
```

[Full Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pB0Ag3)

<sub>***Note** : I am not sure if this is the best approach, or 100 percent foolproof*</sub>

Comment: This flags e.g. my name as accented, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sure it is :P yeah i knew it would fail in certain circumstances. Working on another version, though i am not sure this can be reliably done with out a list

Comment: I am not sure it can be done without full Natural Language Processing, because I believe the exact same character can have multiple meanings. E.g. the Unicode character for *Umlaut dots* (as in my name) and *Trema* (as in coöperation) is actually the same despite having totally different meanings. And neither of the two are accents. An accent signals a change in vocal stress, length, or tone of pronunciation, but e.g. *Umlauts* have a *fundamentally different* pronunciation, so they are considered separate vowels, not accents.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah i think your are right (well know)